# python, how to replace filter replace

Tags: python

```
nums = {'Student Name': [ 'Shrek', 'Shivansh', 'Ishdeep',   
                     'Siddharth', 'Nakul', 'Prakhar', 
                     'Yash', 'Srikar', 'Kaustubh',  
                     'Aditya',  'Manav', 'Dubey'], 
    'Roll No.': [ 18229, 18232, np.nan, 18247, 18136,  
                 np.nan, 18283, 18310, 18102, 18012, 
                 18121, 18168], 
    'Subject ID': [204, np.nan, 201, 105, np.nan, 204, 
                   101, 101, np.nan, 165, 715, np.nan], 
   'Grade Point': [9, np.nan, 7, np.nan, 8, 7, 9, 10, 
                   np.nan, 9, 6, 8]}
```

df = pd.DataFrame(nums)

df

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQTOe.png)

I want replace only [Student Name == Shivansh], [subject ID  == np.nan to '100']

df[(df["Student Name"] == "Shivansh")].df["subject ID"].replace(np.nan, 100)

How can I change the code?

Comment: Please take time to edit and format your question properly

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below line of code:

```
df.loc[df["Student Name"] == "Shivansh", 'Subject ID'] = 100
```